# c# open a specific tab from a different form

Tags: c#

How can I call a certain Tab from a different Form? I have a button in a separate form, and when the user clicks on it, it should take them to a tab page which is in the Main form.

Button

```
private void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Form form1 = new Form();
   //Call a certain Tab in the Main Form          
}
```

Comment: This is probably a good place to start:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610313/listening-to-events-in-main-form-from-another-form-in-c-sharp

Comment: You clearly need a reference to your main form and your main form should expose the functionality to select the desired tab. I would decouple this kind of interaction using some interface.

Comment: I think you are free to close a form *from within code in that form* (e.g. in the button click handler). You would first close the open form and then switch to the desired tab. In order to activate a tab, simply call `tabs.SelectedTab = staticTab;`, where staticTab is a tab which you "kept in mind" somewhere, and tabs is your TabControl.

Comment: Do you mean close the current form that is open? The main Form is called which contains different tabs. Instead of the First tab being called, I want to call the second tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is a bit vague but the answer should be pretty simple.
First create a reference to the first form in your second form, possibly in the constructor.

```
Form mainForm;
public SecondForm(Form mainForm){
    this.mainForm = mainForm;
}
```

Then you can reference in your button event function.

```
private void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   mainForm.YourTabControl.SelectedIndex = indexyouwant;
}
```

Comment: The submit button is in the form which should lead to that TabPage(MainForm). The submit button is not in the MainForm.

Answer (score -1):

Define a method in Form1 to switch tab

```
public void ChangeTab(int tabIndex)
{
      YourTabControl.SelectedIndex = tabIndex;
}
```

Call it in other form:

```
private void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Form form1 = new Form();
   form1.ChangeTab(2);
   //Call a certain Tab in the Main Form          
}
```

Comment: You must create form1 as global var, then access this instance when you click a button

Comment: Have you define ChangeTab in your Form1 class (The form that TabControl belong to)

Comment: I fixed that problem but the main Form is called which contains different tabs. Instead of the First tab being called, I want to call the second tab

Comment: Have you sorted your issue @user122938221 ?

Comment: To some extent, however I'm waiting if there are any more suggestions.